# Doctrine2 - How to define table prefix for orm mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a question regarding doctrine2 mapping configuration. 
I need to store in my database 2 logicaly separated sets of data, so I wanted to have them also separated in code. I store my entities in ditectory 
`\App\Entity` and wanted to store second set under `\App\Entity\External`

This are my doctrine orm settings:

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
            External:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/External'
                prefix: 'App\Entity\External'
                alias: External
```

My question is - can I setup somehow databese table prefixes. I want all my External entities to be automaticaly link with tables prefixed with `external_`, so when I have  `App\Entity\External\Animal` I want it linked to table `external_animal`?

I know I can do this by adding `@Table(name="external_animal"),` annotation in Entity, but I want to have prefix for all "externals" globally.

Comment: Having External inside Entity might be an issue, because the `App` would contain those. You might want to have it in a folder next to Entity instead. You can set a common prefix, but it will require you to write some code. I will link an example answer for one prefix as a duplicate and you will just have to adjust it by looking at the namespace of the entity to decide which prefix to use.

Comment: An example implementation of a table-prefix listener can be found [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html#sql-table-prefixes). Just return at the beginning of the `loadClassMetadata` function if the namespace of the entity that's being processed doesn't match `App\Entity\External`. This way you can create multiple of these listeners for different namespace to desired prefix combinations.